# Job execution time in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have a problem with getting the value form Trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc()
I have four tasks, I can return their names, get triggers for each one of them (each has one) and then call this method from trigger, but it returns null. Funny thing is, thats what I see when I debug my code:

[`Quartz.SimpleTrigger] = {Trigger 'DEFAULT.84cc5914-c8ea-478c-99e9-7616d99654cb':  triggerClass: 'Quartz.SimpleTrigger isVolatile: False calendar: '' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: 03/30/2011 13:31:11}`

So the data I need is clearly there. Is this a bug or does it have something to do with value being nullable? I try to get it like this

```
string nextExecDate = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc().HasValue ? t.GetNextFireTimeUtc().ToString() : "no info";
```

or this way:

```
string nextExecDate = trigger.GetValueOrDefault();
```

both not working. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more code so I can try and reproduce it for you?

Perhaps try adding the following code, it works for me:

```
MessageBox.Show("Next fire time: " + trigger.GetNextFireTimeUTC().ToString())
```